# Frobenius norm and submultiplicativity

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I read (page 8 [here](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF-MAT4350/h09/undervisningsmateriale/lecture7.pdf)) that if $A$ and $B$
are rectangular matrices so that the product $AB$ is defined, then 
$$(1)\quad||AB||_F^2\leq ||A||_F^2||B||_F^2$$

Does that mean that the inequality above also holds when the number of rows of $A$ is larger than the number of columns of $B$? The justification (Cauchy Swartz):

$$||AB||_F^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k(a_i^\top b_j)^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k||a_i||_2^2||b_j||^2_2=||A||_F^2||B||_F^2$$

does not require $k$ (the number of columns of $B$) to equal $n$ (the number of rows of $A$). Intuitively, you could also add imaginary columns of 0's to $B$, so I can believe the claim. On the other hand, in [other places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Definition) I only see $(1)$  claimed for matrix of the same size and have had a hard time finding it claimed for the more general case (where $A$ $B$ are merely multiplicative)  online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the only requirement to have the inequality that you wrote for the Frobenius norm and for arbitrary matrices is that the product $AB$ is defined.

If you are looking for a reference see for example the book Numerical Linear Algebra, by Trefethen and Bau, page 23.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed